# h:commandButton action not call

Tags: richfaces, seam

I'm using Seam 2.3 and i want to call a method action into a h:commandButton. When i click i can see a select query into the console but my method is never call.

```
<h:form id="form">
 <rich:panel id="panelInfoModif"  rendered="#{ClassAction.beanSelected()}">
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{ClassAction.submit()}" >
        <a:ajax execute="@this"></a:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>
  </rich:panel>             
</h:form>
```

Comment: No exceptions? The name of the bean should start with lower-case letter. Also what is the ajax for?

Comment: No exceptions. Ok but its not the real name of my bean. if i remove ajax, i have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) contains a long list of things to check if your button is not working